# How do I make an installable for Microsoft out of a Office Add-in developed for Excel?

Tags: office-js, excel-web-addins

We developed an Office Add-in for Excel using the new web based approach, but for the purpose we require it need it to be installed via an executable. The other mechanisms to publish & install such as sideloading, publishing in the AppSource, Sharepoint etc are not possible given the security measures of the organization that will use it (ie, they have disabled the network sharing and AppSource) -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish

We are looking a way of creating an executable that can do this process. The organization that will use this would rather have an executable that does the network sharing setup for instance.

We tried sideloading, but given the security constraints, cant share the folder where we store the manifest. That is, when accessing the properties of the folder, there is no option to network share.

The AppSource is disabled for all the organization. They dont use the Sharepoint either and the Microsoft 365 is also out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the techniques described in article that you linked to, the only other way to deploy add-ins is described in this blog post: https://theofficecontext.com/2020/03/23/web-add-in-side-loader-tool/